# How does this shell command work?

Tags: shell, ssh

The following command puts the content of the local `id_rsa.pub` into the `authorized_keys` file on the host.

But I don't quite understand how `cat` and `|` works together to achieve this goal, can someone explain?

```
cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh b@B 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
```

Comment: Just wanted to point out the [UUOC](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html) (useless use of cat).  `ssh b@B 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys' < .ssh/id_rsa.pub` is better.

Comment: Good point. Thx @jw013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cat` command outputs contents of the file `.ssh/id_rsa.pub`; the `|` (pipe) receives this text output and then sends (i.e. pipes) the text to `ssh`.

Then, `ssh` uses this text as input for the `cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys` command.

Comment: I think this command can be clear if we ignore ssh part `ssh b@B`. It will become: `cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys`, which I can understand. ;)

Comment: @mitnk pretty much that, if you see that the `cat` after the pipe is running on the other machine.

Answer (score -3):

For `cat` command if no file name is provided it takes it from stdin. In this case its the output of the `|`.